# Php CURL Post not working even with curl enabled

Tags: php, curl

I know that there are many same questions, and I have tries the solution from many of them but still I am unable to figure this out.

I am trying to send a curl post from one server to another like this

```
$array = array("businessname" => "Illusion Softwares");
# try hitting the Tracking via CURL 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite.com/testCurl.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($array));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

This is what I have on the testCurl.php on the server where I am posting

```
echo $_REQUEST['businessname'];
exit;
```

When I run the page it keeps on loading and loading and loading with a time out error message at last.

I have enabled curl on both the servers.

What am I missing ??

Answer (score 0):

add this line,

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite.com/testCurl.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("businessname" => "Illusion Softwares"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

Comment: Let me try that. I will post you back in a moment.

Comment: Still not working. and here is the link to my website
http://hf-dev.info/curlPost.php

Comment: this page hf-dev.info/curlPost.php has your code exactly, but still not working.

Comment: remove this line and check -->  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$array = array("businessname" => "Illusion Softwares");
$headers = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml",
            "Content-length: " . strlen($array),
            "Connection: close",
        );

# try hitting the Tracking via CURL 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite.com/testCurl.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            curl_error($ch);
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            curl_close($ch);
            return TRUE;
```

Comment: @ Satish, I will try you code and post you in a moment.

Comment: I tried that but it has still the same issue. I am getting the request time out error.

Comment: for request time out error use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

Comment: I dont think that will work because the process which must take around 1-2 seconds is taking so long.

I am posting the data to this URL http://www.dev.businesssupportcenter.com/testCurl.php?businessname=Illusion%20Softwares, if you run this URL manually in browser you will get the response

Answer (score 0):

This curl options setup will get you the info you need to find out what went wrong

You may need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);`

```
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
```

Then you need to check for error, if no error then look at the Request and Response Headers.  Below I get the Response header and the Request Header is in $info.

```
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch)){
      $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
      echo $data;
  }
  else {
    $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
    $responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
    $data= substr($data,$skip);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $info = var_export($info,true);
   }
   echo $responseHeader . $info . $data ;
```

If you get an Error is is likely a problem with the request.

To customize your request here is an example:

```
$request = array();
$request[] = 'Host: xxxxxxx';
$request[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0';
$request[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$request[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$request[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$request[] = 'DNT: 1';
$request[] = 'Cookie: xxxx
$request[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$request[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
```

Then include:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
```